# Graph API gets posts only with messages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

It's simple question it's possible to posts from graph api, but only these with messages?

```
graph.facebook.com/name?fields=feed
```

This get all posts, even if there is no message in post (someone just for example uplaod a image - without description).

I would filter that, but can't find the way to to that.

You can do

```
name?fields=feed{id}
```

to get only ids, but if you replace 'id' to 'message' it does not get pure posts with messages only.

I tried also with /search?q=... and with no success.

Any options?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter by posts with messages only, you would have to do that on your own after getting all posts.

Comment: Yep, you could be right, sadly..
So, thanks, I just think I can avoid that way